# Having issues with mapping an array with .join

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mapping, filtering

I am unable to map the batters section of the array. The assignment asks: "batters": "all of the batter types as a string. I am unable to map it without getting multiple arrays. The goal is to have batters display such as

batter:"Regular", "Chocolate", "Blueberry"

I've tried the .join method of an array to have to show just as a string, continuously getting errors.

```
sabio.page.startUp = function () {
  console.log(oldCakesObject);

  let newCakes = oldCakesObject.items.item.map(sabio.page.mapCakes);
  console.log(newCakes);
}

sabio.page.mapCakes = function (cake) {
  let numberOfFillings = 0;
  let batters = batter.join()

  if (cake.fillings) {
    numberOfFillings = cake.fillings.filling.length
  }
  return {
    id: cake.id,
    type: cake.type,
    name: cake.name,
    ppu: cake.ppu,
    // batters: cake.items.batter,
    ingredients: cake.topping,
    countOfFillings: numberOfFillings
  }
};

{
  "items":
  {
    "item":
    [
      {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        {
          "batter":
            [
              { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
              { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
              { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
              { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
```

I am getting errors when trying to console.log the batters. Only issue is with batters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the batter array of objects to array of just the `type` values before using `join()`

```
let batters = cake.batters.batter.map(item => item.type).join()
```